# What is the meaning of exit (not exit'') in J?

Tags: j

I recently installed J and was playing in jconsole.  Here's what then end of my session looked like:

```
    quit
|value error: quit
    exit
2!:55
```

I searched the web and quickly found that the correct exit code is

```
    exit''
```

Since meaningless words give value errors, and no substring of "exit" is valid J, why is a value given for "exit"? What does 2!:55 mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2!:55` is the definition of `exit`. When you enter a verb without arguments, J shows you its definition. eg:

```
f =: *:
f 5
25
f
*:
```

Same with every other predefined verb:

```
echo
0 0&$@(1!:2&2)
every
&>
each
&.>
```

etc.

Comment: [1/2] To add on to this excellent answer, and perhaps clarify for OP who's new to J: all of J's built-in (primitive) functions are spelled symbolically; that is, an ASCII glyph (`!"#$%&*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_{|}~`) or any printable ASCII character followed by any number of dots (`.`) and colons (`:`). In particular, the two-letter primitive `!:` is the *foreign* function, which controls all access to the host system. For example, `1!:n` is the "file" family of functions, and `1!:1` is "read file", `1!:2`" is "write file", and so on, whereas the `7!:` functions are related to memory (management).

Comment: [2/2] The specific function `2!:55` is the verb *exit*; the numeric codes `2` and `55` were chosen as a mnemonic: `255` is the "last" value of an (eight-bit) byte, and `2!:55 ''` is the "last" thing you want to do in a J session. Like all verbs, `exit` *requires an argument* to be invoked. If its argument is a single, atomic, integer, that becomes the exit code of the J executable (with some caveats), otherwise, if the argument is not an atomic integer (as with `exit''`), the exit code will simply be 0. Either way, the J session will end.

Comment: @Dan, those comments deserve  `answer` status.